# How to address similar sublevel values in the R list?

Tags: r, list, indexing

Sorry, most probably that's been discussed already, but I couldn't find the exact match.
Let's say I've created the list of values with multiple sublevels identical between all the first-order values. Something like that:

```
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(type = letters[1:10], A = runif(10), B = runif(10)*5, C = runif(10)/2, D = 1:10)
correlations <- apply(data[,2:5], 2, cor.test, data$A)
str(correlations)
```

That results in the list with identical sublevel names ("p-values", "estimate" and many others). Like that:
[image]

Is there a "simple" way to directly address each sublevel as a group ? Like `correlations$..$p-value` or something similar. So, one doesn't need to conduct additional manipulations creating a separate dataframe for that ?
Thank you!

Comment: Since you have a named list, you can access the leaves with `correlations$A$p.value` or `correlations[["A"]]$p.value`. Weren't they named, you would have to access them by number, ``correlations[[1]]$p.value``.

Comment: And to get the values of all list members in one instruction, `sapply(correlations, \(x) x$statistic)`. (Or replace `statistic` by any other element you want.)

Comment: Thanks, Rui. I mean to get all p.values (not only for A sublist). So, there is no a direct way to do index that via base R tools, only through other functions like sapply ? Thank you!

Comment: This ````sapply```` solution is actually very elegant, thank you! Could I educate myself and ask how you use "x" in this code and how R distinguishes that from any other "x" string possibly present in my dataset ?

Comment: `x`is the anonymous function variable, `sapply(data, \(x) ...)` is equivalent to `sapply(data, function(x) ...)`. If you have names conflicts, use another name. For instance, `.x` with a dot is an unfrequent name and can many times replace `x`.

Answer (score 3):

In base R we `unlist`, `t`ransform and coerce `as.data.frame`, `rbind` and `type.convert`.

```
> lapply(correlations, unlist) |> lapply(t) |> lapply(as.data.frame) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
        statistic.t parameter.df           p.value       estimate.cor null.value.correlation alternative
A               Inf            8                 0                  1                      0   two.sided
B 0.188506772777935            8 0.855173531621001 0.0664996814881612                      0   two.sided
C -1.03567121974133            8 0.330644220368375 -0.343839423420549                      0   two.sided
D -1.06853889681018            8 0.316456566017573 -0.353406931296896                      0   two.sided
                                method            data.name          conf.int1         conf.int2
A Pearson's product-moment correlation newX[, i] and data$A                  1                 1
B Pearson's product-moment correlation newX[, i] and data$A -0.587735055360001 0.668150552690274
C Pearson's product-moment correlation newX[, i] and data$A -0.800224784794599 0.364752207983986
D Pearson's product-moment correlation newX[, i] and data$A -0.804107757875213 0.355272603243911
```

Note, that `apply` is designed for `matrices`, but we have a `"data.frame"`, so `lapply` is more appropriate to get the `correlations` object.

```
lapply(data[-1], cor.test, data$A)
```

### Edit

Maybe better to use a custom `cor_fun`.

```
> cor_fun <- \(x, y) {
+   type.convert(as.data.frame(t(unlist(cor.test(x, y)))), as.is=TRUE)
+ }
> 
> t(sapply(data[-1], cor_fun, data$A))
  statistic.t parameter.df p.value   estimate.cor null.value.correlation alternative
A Inf         8            0         1            0                      "two.sided"
B 0.1885068   8            0.8551735 0.06649968   0                      "two.sided"
C -1.035671   8            0.3306442 -0.3438394   0                      "two.sided"
D -1.068539   8            0.3164566 -0.3534069   0                      "two.sided"
  method                                 data.name conf.int1  conf.int2
A "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x and y" 1          1        
B "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x and y" -0.5877351 0.6681506
C "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x and y" -0.8002248 0.3647522
D "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x and y" -0.8041078 0.3552726
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `broom::tidy` to convert the test results into data.frames, and finally `bind` everything together. The resulting data.frame will make everything easier downstream, because similar statistics will be grouped column-wise, and easily extracted as vectors.
This will work for the presented use case,in which the list elements are summaries of statistics tests. For other general uses with lists, there are more involved (and element-class-agnostic) ways.

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)


correlations |> 
    map(tidy) |> 
    list_rbind(names_to = "index")

# A tibble: 4 × 9
  index estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method                               alternative
  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                <chr>      
1 A       1        Inf       0             8    1         1     Pearson's product-moment correlation two.sided  
2 B       0.0665     0.189   0.855         8   -0.588     0.668 Pearson's product-moment correlation two.sided  
3 C      -0.344     -1.04    0.331         8   -0.800     0.365 Pearson's product-moment correlation two.sided  
4 D      -0.353     -1.07    0.316         8   -0.804     0.355 Pearson's product-moment correlation two.sided
```

If we assign the list from above to a `results` object, extraction of its elements is straightforward:

```
results$p.value
[1] 0.0000000 0.8551735 0.3306442 0.3164566
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Guedes! Is there a direct way in base R to index those sublevels ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to avoid specific packages? I say that because this is just the perfect use case for such a simple approach, and the packages I used are very useful in many scenarios...

Comment: for a strictly base-R approach, I would do something like in @jay.sf's answer